# Video encoding for web streaming with Raspberry Pi

Tags: video, streaming

I have a [Sony Camcorder HXR-NX5E](http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/product/broadcast-products-camcorders-nxcam-avchd/hxr-nx5e/specifications/#specifications) that I want to use for web streaming on Youtube, Facebook, etc. I would like to know if there is a way to use Raspberry Pi as a video encoder open source to stream videos online with low latency and 720px HD resolution through a wi-fi connection. Is there anything I can do? The usual video encoder products available from Teradek, Livesteam, Blackmagic Design, are very expensive and not always fully compatible with the different online platforms or socials.

These are the connections available:

[image: Sony HXR-NX5E connectors]

Any guide or suggestion to reach this purpose would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site Stefano. We have a great many questions already which relate to [webcam video streaming](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=webcam%20stream). I notice from its specs that your camera has a USB output - can it function as a webcam?

Comment: Nope...unfortunately not! The USB output works only to transfer data...I have an HDMI connection but don't think can work like that.

Comment: If it has an HDMI output it may be worth taking a look over [this Q&A](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64203/can-the-raspberry-pi-be-used-as-a-second-monitor-for-a-pc/64233#64233) which has a few details on Auvidea devices which might be viable. Does the camera have any other output options which allow live video to be transported to an external device?

Comment: It has connectors for reproduction on TV only

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ChickenDevs/webcast

This might help. I have been looking for the same answer and found this which does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/115804)